# Bash read line and replace value with previous line

Tags: shell, awk

I have the below XML file and I want to replace value in  with value of Product ID.

I am using below code but it's replacing same product in both the lines.

I have also provided sample source and target content below.

```
 while read line
 do
 count=`echo $line | grep "Product ID" | wc -l`
 if [ $count -eq "1" ]
  then
 product=`echo "$line" | grep "Product ID"|awk -F "=" '{print $2}' | awk 
 '{print $1}'`

 name=`grep "$line" -B 1 test.xml | tail -1|sed 's/\///g;s/<Name>//g' | 
  awk '{print $1}'`

 echo $line | sed "s/$name/$product/g" >> data.xml
 else
 echo "$line" >> data.xml
 fi

 done < test.xml
```

Below is the Source Format:

```
 <Products>
<Product ID="ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
  <Name>1234</Name>  
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="A">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">00</Value>
     </Values>
</Product>
 <Product ID="XYZ1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
   <Name>1234</Name>
  <Value AttributeID="A">4</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">10</Value>
     </Values>
 </Product>
```

Below will be the Output format:

```
<Products>
<Product ID="ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
  <Name>ABC1234</Name>  
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="A">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">00</Value>
     </Values>
</Product>
 <Product ID="XYZ1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
   <Name>XYZ1234</Name>
  <Value AttributeID="A">4</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">10</Value>
     </Values>
 </Product>
```

Please suggest any other approach.

Comment: Could you please post 3 simple points.1st- Sample of input, 2nd- Sample of output and 3rd- what you have tried to solve this in code tags.

Comment: upto done < test.xml  --- code tried                                                                                      Below is the Source Format  --- sample input                                                                   Below will be the Output format  --- sample Output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: In case as per OP's comment if a line is having more than `"` values in it then I am selecting very first value between `"`to `"`.

```
awk -F'[>"<]' '
/Product ID/{
    match($0,/"[^"]*/)
    val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
/<Name>/{
    sub(/>.*</,">"val"<")
}
1'  Input_file
```

Output getting after running above code is as follows:

```
awk -F'[>"<]' '
/Product ID/{
    match($0,/"[^"]*/)
    val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
/<Name>/{
    sub(/>.*</,">"val"<")
}
1'  Input_file
 <Products>
<Product ID="ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
  <Name>ABC1234</Name>  
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="A">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">00</Value>
     </Values>
</Product>
 <Product ID="XYZ1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
   <Name>XYZ1234</Name>
  <Value AttributeID="A">4</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">10</Value>
     </Values>
 </Product>
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[>"<]' '
/Product ID/{
    match($0,/".*"/)
    val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}
/<Name>/{
    sub(/>.*</,">"val"<")
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks Its working.    but facing issue with below file format.                              Input FIle :                                                                                                             <Products>
    <Product ID="ABC1234"  UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT">
      <Name>1234</Name>  
      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="A">1</Value>
    
   </Values>
    </Product>
  <Product ID="XYZ1234"  UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
       <Name>1234</Name>
   <Value AttributeID="A">4</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="B">10</Value>
   </Values>
</Product>

Comment: @navku, not sure, sorry not clear. Please be clear for what is not  working, as code was  written as per your given sample Input_file only.

Comment: For my question its working fine fine but I have one more set of file which  has below format                                                                                                              <Products> <Product ID="ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT">   and I need to replace only with "ABC1234" but it replacing all the fields after ProductID.

Comment: @navku, please try my EDIT code once and let me know?

Comment: Its creating output as below.                                                                           <Products>
    <Product ID="ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
      <Name>ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT</Name>
      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="A">1</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="B">00</Value>
                 </Values>
    </Product>
         <Product ID="XYZ1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT">
       <Name>XYZ1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT</Name>
          <Value AttributeID="A">4</Value>
                         </Values>
</Product>

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 updated the input and ouput format in the question

Comment: @navku, I updated the output I am getting after running my EDIT command(new one), please check if you have run EDIT command only and let me know?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks a lot for your help buddy. Its working fine. Have a great weekend :)

Comment: @navku, awesome, glad that it helped you, keep leaning and keep sharing on this great site SO.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
 perl -0777 -pe ' s/(<Product ID=\"(\S+)\".+?<Name>)(.+?)</$1$2</msg '
```

With the given inputs

```
$ cat navku.xml
 <Products>
<Product ID="ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
  <Name>1234</Name>
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="A">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">00</Value>
     </Values>
</Product>
 <Product ID="XYZ1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
   <Name>1234</Name>
  <Value AttributeID="A">4</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">10</Value>
     </Values>
 </Product>
$ perl -0777 -pe ' s/(<Product ID=\"(\S+)\".+?<Name>)(.+?)</$1$2</msg ' navku.xml
 <Products>
<Product ID="ABC1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
  <Name>ABC1234</Name>
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="A">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">00</Value>
     </Values>
</Product>
 <Product ID="XYZ1234" UserID="XYX" SUperUserID="ROOT" >
   <Name>XYZ1234</Name>
  <Value AttributeID="A">4</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="B">10</Value>
     </Values>
 </Product>
$
```